# How to change tab order on product page?

Tags: magento2.2

I added some custom tabs to magento, but I can't change order of that. I tried do it by xml by set priority and I even tried overwrite table in details.phtml in fona core, but it don't work. I want do it something like this
PRODUCT TAB | CUSTOM TAB | REVIEWS, but now it's PRODUCT TAB | REVIEWS | CUSTOM TAB